# Why is JavaFX's WebView is flashing red and green?

Tags: java, groovy, webview, gradle, javafx

I'm just starting out with JavaFX, and I wanted to put a WebView into a Window:

```
public static class HelloJavaFXWeb extends Application {
    @Override public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        final Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, Color.DODGERBLUE);
        WebView webView = new WebView();
        webView.getEngine().load("http://www.google.com");
        root.getChildren().add(webView);

        stage.setTitle("HelloWorld in JavaFX 2.0");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}

Application.launch(HelloJavaFXWeb.class);
```

It looks ever so simple, but for some reason the draw regions are being highlighted with red and green when moving the mouse around. How can I disable the flashing colors?

[image: moving mouse over the WebView]

### Update: the problem is with Groovy/Gradle interaction

Here's an extremely minimal repro
(put all this in a `build.gradle` and run `gradle tasks --no-daemon`):

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        def jvm = org.gradle.internal.jvm.Jvm.current()
        if (jvm.javaVersion.isJava7()) {
            classpath files("${jvm.jre.homeDir}/lib/jfxrt.jar")
        }
    }
}

import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

class HelloJavaFXWeb extends Application {
    @Override public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        final Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, Color.DODGERBLUE);
        WebView webView = new WebView();
        webView.getEngine().load("http://www.google.com");
        root.getChildren().add(webView);

        stage.setTitle("HelloWorld in JavaFX 2.0");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}

Application.launch(HelloJavaFXWeb.class);
```

I just noticed that it outputs some logging after termination
(this was hidden before, probably because I used a Gradle daemon which swallowed it):

> =========== Performance Statistics =============
>   Time/Invocations count:
>   com.sun.webpane.perf.WCFontPerfLogger.*: ...
>   com.sun.webpane.perf.WCGraphicsPerfLogger.*: ...

I'm using `jdk1.7.0_80_x64/jre/lib/jfxrt.jar` on Windows 7 x64 Ultimate.

Tried the following Java versions I had on my computer:

```
+-----------------+-----------+---------+
|     version     | flashing  | logging |
+-----------------+-----------+---------+
| jdk1.7.0_05_x86 |      no JavaFX      |
| jdk1.7.0_80_x64 | yes       | yes     |
| jdk1.7.0_80_x86 | yes       | no      |
| jre1.7.0_80_x86 | yes       | no      |
| jre1.7.0_80_x64 | yes       | no      |
| jre1.8.0_45_x86 | no        | no      |
| jre1.8.0_45_x64 | no        | no      |
+-----------------+-----------+---------+
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81774/discussion-between-twisterrob-and-nwdx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some hours of going deep into `jfxrt.jar`, trial and error and with the help of @NwDx here's a summary of what's going on.

The Gradle build system messes with the JUL root logger and sets the default logging level to `FINER` from the original `INFO`. This activates a lot of internal mechanisms inside the JavaFX runtime. Most notably:

- Clip region debug is dependent on a JUL Logger
- `PerfLogger`s are dependent on some JUL Logger levels
- lot of other unnecessary logging, probably to /dev/null

If you're careless you can use: `LogManager.getLogManager().reset()` to fix everything. More careful patients may continue reading.

#### Clip Region Debug

There's some visual debugging code guarded by a [`log.isLoggable(Level.FINE)`](https://github.com/barchart/barchart-javafx-study/blob/master/barchart-oracle-javafx-2.2.7/src/main/java/com/sun/webpane/sg/prism/WCGraphicsPrismContext.java#L259) in `com.sun.webpane.sg.prism.WCGraphicsPrismContext`.

It is a known bug filed here: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8096483
Looking at the fix version: anything before 1.8.0u40 is susceptible to this unwanted visual debugging (see table in question). In 1.8.0u40+ you can `-Dcom.sun.webkit.debugDrawClipShape=true` to enable this "feature".

To be on the safe side it's worth disabling the logging for that class either by configuring JUL or:

```
String name = com.sun.webpane.sg.prism.WCGraphicsPrismContext.class.getName();
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(name).setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);
```

#### PerfLogger logging

As mentioned in the question there's some diagnostic info being spit out to stdout. [`PerfLogger` checks the `FINE` level](https://github.com/barchart/barchart-javafx-study/blob/master/barchart-oracle-javafx-2.2.7/src/main/java/com/sun/webpane/perf/PerfLogger.java#L81) as well. The source of those messages are the following:

- `com.sun.webpane.perf.WCGraphicsPerfLogger`
- `com.sun.webpane.perf.WCFontPerfLogger`
- `com.sun.webpane.platform.Invoker` named `Locks`
- [`TextBreakIteratorJava`](https://oss.oracle.com/projects/webkit-java-mods/src/trunk/Source/WebCore/platform/java/TextBreakIteratorJava.cpp) in `jfxwebkit.dll` is named `XXXX` via the [LOG_PERF_RECORD](https://oss.oracle.com/projects/webkit-java-mods/src/trunk/Source/WebCore/platform/java/JavaEnv.h)
  ... someone took the example literally, whyyy? :(

The easiest way to disable this is:

```
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger('com.sun.webpane.perf').setLevel(Level.OFF)
```

because [the package name is hardcoded](https://github.com/barchart/barchart-javafx-study/blob/master/barchart-oracle-javafx-2.2.7/src/main/java/com/sun/webpane/perf/PerfLogger.java#L76) or the `Logger` instances are in that package.

#### Everyhing else

It's probably worth making the log level higher (INFO-OFF) for all `com.sun.*` and `javafx.*` packages to prevent further weirdness or performance degradation.

For any further info see [our chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81774/discussion-between-twisterrob-and-nwdx).